# Android lost keystore

Tags: android, android-keystore

So basically we just lost a keystore AND the backup keystore. However we MIGHT know the password to the original keystore.

My question is if we know the password to our original keystore, can we regenerate the keystore file and if so how?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The keystore contains the private and public keys. These are generated using a random number. Even if you have the password, this would just allow you to decrypt access to the keys. You would need to know the random number that was used to generate the keys in order to recreate the keystore. Sorry.

Comment: In the future, check the keystore into your source code repository along with a README containing the necessary passwords. It isn't secure, but at least you won't have this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are enrolled App Signing, the simplest is replacing the keystore file.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Check out the Lost or compromised private keys section.

Please submit the form with pem file in this link.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs